# pysnmp nextcmd stops on timeout

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to perform a snmp walk on certain networking devices.
On some netwroking devices I succeed to go through all the devices oids and on some networking devices I don't succeed to go through all the devices oids.
Here is my code:

```
cmdGen = cmdgen.AsynCommandGenerator()
cmdGen.asyncNextCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('ip', 161),timeout=timeout,retries=retries),
    ((1,3),),
    (cbFun_Walk, None))
cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

The problem is that sometimes asyncCommandGenerator gets a timeout on a certaion oid and exists out of the thread.

[image]

As you can see the thread reaches some oid, gets a timeout error, and then quits the thread.
So i would like to know how to continue the snmpwalk even if a timed out oid was reached.
Basically if asyncCommandGenerator reaches a timed out oid, it should just continue with the walk and get the rest of the oids.
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, you can't skip the "next" OID on request timeout, as you will not know what is the next OID then. I can see two workarounds  here:

1. Repeat your GETNEXT request for the same OID for as long as it takes to get a response. By increasing request timeout and retry count. Proper SNMP responder should ultimately respond to all valid requests.
2. Try to guess what is the "next" OID past the one you can't get response for. This is generally MIB-dependent and in many cases may require a non-trivial fuzziness. Once you somehow picked the next OID, just re-start your original code with the guessed OID. That would effectively "skip" the problem OID (or many of them at once if your guess is not perfect). In case of another timeout you may consider changing your next OID selection logic --  chances are you are still hitting the same timing out OID.

Comment: I get what your saying and I can easily implement this, but I still think there must be a simpler way to do an snmpwalk in pysnmp.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the "next" OID without guessing?

Comment: Next OID is MIB-dependent. If it is a statically defined the scalar, MIB lookup by previous OID would reveal the next OID. However if it's a SNMP table entry things become more dynamic and not always guessable.